# How to fetch data from different sources (device cache, web server and sqlite database) synchronously?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executor

and happy new year!
I am Learning android development using java, and I started by creating my first application using **architecture components** following this tutorial: 
[Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide.)

I have a good understanding about **android architecture design** and the other basic stuff. But, I still have a problem in handling background tasks because there are many classes that provide multi-threading like : **Executor**, **IntentService** and **asynctask**..

**My code :**

- Repository class:

  ```
  public class MovieRpository  {
  private IWebService m_webService;
  private Movie _movie;
  private AppExecuters m_executers;

  private MovieRpository(AppExecuters executers, TMDB webService){
     this.m_executers = executers;
     this.m_webService = webService;
  }

   private static MovieRpository m_singleInstance;

   public static MovieRpository getInstance(){
      if(m_singleInstance == null){
           m_singleInstance = new 
   MovieRpository(AppExecuters.getInstance(), new TMDB(new JsonParser<Movie>()));
  }
  return  m_singleInstance;
  }

   public LiveData<Movie> getMovie( String movieId){
     final MutableLiveData<Movie> _liveDataMovie = new MutableLiveData<Movie>();
     m_executers.networkIO().execute(()->{
         _movie =(Movie)m_webService.getObject(movieId);});
     _liveDataMovie.setValue(_movie);
     return _liveDataMovie;
    }
   }
  ```

### **My problem :**

In Repository class when i use debugger inside the second thread which is created by ***m_executers.networkIO()*** **_movie** has a value inside the network thread. but, it is always null outside execute method.

### **The rest of my code:**

-**IWebService interface**

```
  public interface IWebService<T> {
    public T getObject(String url);
  }
```

- **TMDB:**

  ```
  public class TMDB implements IWebService<Movie> {
     private JsonParser<Movie> m_jsonParser;
     private Movie _movie;
     public TMDB(JsonParser<Movie> jsonParser){
     m_jsonParser = jsonParser;
  }
  @Override
  public Movie getObject(String url) {

    try {
        HttpURLConnection _connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
        _connection.setRequestMethod(Settings.CONNECTION_GET_METHOD);
        _connection.setConnectTimeout(Settings.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        _connection.setReadTimeout(Settings.DATA_READ_TIMEOUT);
        _connection.connect();
        InputStreamReader _streamReader = new InputStreamReader(_connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader _bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(_streamReader);
        StringBuilder _data = new StringBuilder();
        String _line;
        while((_line = _bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ){
            _data.append(_line);
        }
        _bufferedReader.close();
        _streamReader.close();

         Gson _gson = new Gson();
        _movie = _gson.fromJson(_data.toString(), Movie.class);

    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return _movie;
    }
  }
  ```
- **AppExecuters singleton class for managing threads:**

  ```
  public class AppExecuters {
  private static AppExecuters m_singltonInstance;
  private Executor m_NetworkIO;
  private Executor m_diskIO;
  private Executor m_mainThread;
  private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

  private AppExecuters(Executor diskThread, Executor networkThread, Executor mainThread){
      this.m_diskIO = diskThread;
      this.m_mainThread = mainThread;
      this.m_NetworkIO = networkThread;
  }
  public static AppExecuters getInstance(){
      if(m_singltonInstance == null){
          // In-order to make the singleton instance synchronized between all threads.
          synchronized (LOCK){
              m_singltonInstance = new AppExecuters(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3), new MainThread());
          }
      }
      return m_singltonInstance;
  }

  public  Executor networkIO(){
      return m_NetworkIO;
  }
  public  Executor diskIO(){
      return m_diskIO;
  }
  public  Executor mainThread(){
      return m_mainThread;
  }

  private static class MainThread implements Executor{
      private Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
      @Override
      public void execute(Runnable command) {
          mainThreadHandler.post(command);
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- I also need to know the best practice for managing
  threads in such case.

Comment: ......oh my. Okay, the quick and easy answer here is that you should avoid setting mutable fields across threads and instead you should just use `mutableLiveData.postValue(value)` as it was made specifically to send values from background thread to main thread. So just remove `private Movie _movie;` and it'll work. Kind of.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was helpful..As I said  I am still an android newbie..I have been reading during the past three days in the android docs about some topics like Dependency Injection and Multi-threading and I am lost now.. I need any article that compare between all the threading classes and give the use case of each one of them.

Comment: Just refer to https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/